# hibernate вставляет внешний ключ как null

Tags: java, база-данных, hibernate, spring-boot, foreign-key

После добавления нового топика в базе данных создается сообщение с id_topic = null.
Из-за этого при попытке достать топик из базы данных не достается связная с ним сущность

Описание сущностей:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Data
public abstract class AbstractEntity {
    @Column(name = "created")
    private String created;
}
```

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "message")
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Message extends AbstractEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "text", nullable = false)
    private String text;

    @Column(name = "author")
    private String author;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_topic")
    private Topic topic;
}
```

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "topic")
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Topic extends AbstractEntity{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    private String id;

    @Column(name="name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "topic", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Message> messages;
}
```

Так же приложу метод topicService который отвечает за создание нового топика

```
 @Override
    public TopicAllFieldsDto add(NewTopicRequestDto request) {

        MessageWithoutTopicDto messageFromRequest = request.getMessage();

        if (messageFromRequest == null) {
            throw new NullFieldException("message is null");
        }

        if (request.getTopicName() == null) {
            throw new NullFieldException("topicName is null");
        }

        if (messageRepository.existsById(messageFromRequest.getId())) {
            throw new MessageAlreadyInDatabaseException("При создании топика было сообщение с id, " +
                    "которое уже есть в базе данных. id = " + messageFromRequest.getId());
        }

        try {
            ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(messageFromRequest.getCreated());

            if (dateTime.isAfter(ZonedDateTime.now())) {
                throw new WrongCreationTimeException("было указано время создания которое еще не наступило. " +
                        "Указанное время создания: " + messageFromRequest.getCreated());
            }

        } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
            throw new WrongCreationTimeException(e.getMessage());
        }

        if (messageFromRequest.getText() == null) {
            throw new NullFieldException("message text is null");
        }

        Message message = Message.builder()
                .id(messageFromRequest.getId())
                .text(messageFromRequest.getText())
                .author(messageFromRequest.getAuthor())
                .build();

        message.setCreated(messageFromRequest.getCreated());

        Topic topic = Topic.builder()
                .name(request.getTopicName())
                .messages(Arrays.asList(message))
                .build();

        topic.setCreated(ZonedDateTime.now().toString());

        Topic savedTopic = topicRepository.save(topic);

        return topicToDto(savedTopic);

    }
```

Так же приложу DTO

```
@Getter
@Builder
public class TopicAllFieldsDto {
    private String id;

    private String name;

    private String created;

    private List<MessageWithoutTopicDto> messages;
}
```

```
@Getter
@Builder
public class NewTopicRequestDto {

    private String topicName;

    private MessageWithoutTopicDto message;
}
```

Я пытался менять CascadeType у сущностей, но мне кажется что с этим все нормально (это собственное и не помогло).
Я находил подобные проблемы на stackoverflow, но ответы мне не помогли.